# Количество повторений подстроки в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть рабочий код нахождения количества повторений подстроки в строке:

```
def count_substring(string,sub_string):
    l=len(sub_string)
    count=0
    for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
        if(string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string ):
            count+=1
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()

    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Может кто-то подробно объяснить как работает цикл `for`? Что там происходит и что значит эта запись?:

`if(string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string ):`, а именно часть с двоеточием

т.к я не видел в учебниках по питону такого синтаксиса

Спасибо!

Comment: Часть с двоеточием называется [срезы](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html). В данном случае берётся подстрока от `string` с индекса `i` до индекса `i + len(sub_string)` _(т.е. вырезается подстрока длинной `len(sub_string)`)_ и эта подстрока сравнивается с `sub_string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это называется "срез" и странно, что вы не видели это в учебнике - это база

```
data[start:end:step]
```

показывает как резать список (строку и т.д.) `data` - начиная с позиции `start`, заканчивая позицией (не включая ее) `end` и с шагом `step`

если не указан шаг, он считается равным 1

если не не указан `end`, он считается равным размеру списка

Например:

```
data[7:]
```

сформировать список из всех элементов списка `data`, начиная с 7

```
data[:15]
```

сформировать список из всех элементов списка `data`, заканчивая 14ым

```
data[7:15:3]
```

сформировать список из каждого 3его элемента списка `data`, начиная с 7 и заканчивая 14ым, т.е. 7, 10, 13

```
data[::-1]
```

развернуть список задом наперед - т.е. сформировать список начиная с последнего элемента и заканчивая первым

и т.д.

В вашем случае

```
string[i:i+len(sub_string)]
```

означает взять из строки `string` подстроку размером `len(sub_string)]`, начиная с позиции `i`